# Android Regular Expression for String "X-XX XXXXX"

Tags: android, regex

How to make a regular expression for String `B-SL 55885` ? Actually I want to validate license plate number for vehicle.

Generally: `X-XX XXXXX`

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Have you tried something to solve this?

Comment: Do you want only letters and numbers?

Comment: We don't know the format of the license plate in your country. The most we can do is make a wild guess based on the single example you gave. Can you elaborate on the format?

Answer (score 2):

This ought to do it:

```
^[A-Z]-[A-Z]{2} \d{5}$
```

Note that this is what you asked for: a regex.  When you represent it as a string literal as for use in a `Pattern`, it looks like this:

```
"^[A-Z]-[A-Z]{2} \\d{5}$"
```

This is a trivial regex problem. You should spend some time reading the [documents for `Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and writing small examples for yourself in order to learn. This will be quicker than waiting for someone else to do the work.

Comment: Its working fine but there is an issue. See the difference.

`^[A-Z]-[A-Z]{2} \d{5}$`
`^[A-Z]-[A-Z]{2} \\d{5}$`

Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Actually what I wrote is correct. You asked for a regular expression, not for a string literal containing a regular expression. The regular expression has a single backslash `\d`.  Double backslashes are Java quoted string literal syntax. If you were e.g. reading the regex from a file, neither quotes nor double backslash would be correct.  I should add that this is a trivial regex. You should spend a little time with the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html .  This will be much quicker than waiting for someone else to do the work.